# ASP.NET Identity - How to manage claims?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, claims

I would like to implement claims based authorization in a Web Api project. I understand the idea of claims and can manually add a claim to a user and authorize a request based on it. However, I don't know how I should manage the claims, assign them to users and update them in future.

For example, say I have a Product entity and ProductCreate, ProductRead, ProductUpdate and ProductDelete claims for the CRUD operations on this entity. So I have a few questions:

1. I can store the claims in the DB, but what is the best way to add the "default" claims to a user on registration?
2. If I add new functionality to list the products which is only authorized if the user has the ProductList claim - new users would get this claim, but how would I add this claim to all existing users in the system?
3. Should there be a limit on the number of claims associated with a user? In a larger system with many entities, a user could end up with hundreds of claims

As I said, I know how to physically add the claims to the user etc., but it's more the bigger picture of the process of how you would manage claims and users in a real world example.

Thanks!

UPDATE
Thanks Brendan, I appreciate your help! I don't know if I'm misunderstanding something fundamental or if the answer is staring me in the face - either way, I'm not getting it.

So I have web api and would like to give granular access to the different controller methods. As the Admin, I want to be authorized on all calls so I should have all claims. Registered users should have read access to some methods and you as a moderator should have update and create access to some. My understanding is that these claims should be stored in a DB (SQL server in my case) somewhere and "assigned" to the user when they register. Using Asp.Net Identity, each user's claims would be stored in the AspNetUserClaims table, so when they login they get all their claims in the token by default. Simples!

What I am missing is the process of how you would handle the claims that should be assigned to a user when they register, what claims should a Moderator get etc. and how would you add / remove privileges. It doesn't seem right to me to have this in the code as adding a new claim in the system would require a rebuild and new deployment.

Also, if I add new functionality which requires new claims for different types of user, how would I make sure that the next time an existing user logs in they get the new claims as well as the ones they were assigned when the first registered.

I hope I am making sense, I may be mixing up some of the Role-based thinking with some of the Claims-based thinking which could be the source of my confusion. I just haven't seen any examples of how you would manage an application with many, many claims in the real world.

Thanks again!

Comment: You add claims via the Manager classes that come with ASP.NET Identity (`AddClaimAsync`).  This will in fact add them to the `AspNetUserClaims` table, such that when the user logs in, these claims are automatically added to the ClaimsIdentity of the user.

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I know how to add Claims to a user, but that will add all claims to all users. How should I manage adding specific claims to users e.g. say I want new sign-ups to only have ProductRead and ProductUpdate access - it doesn't seem right to hard code these in the registration code? How SHOULD I do this?

Comment: That would entirely depend on the architecture / structure of your application.  Can you expand on that to reduce the likelihood of this becoming an opinion-based question?

Comment: Hi Brendan, I have added an update to the main question which will hopefully make things clearer. Thanks

Comment: Ah - got it.  I think the easiest thing for you to do is write a migration that adds the new claims to the specific users as and when you add them to the application.  If you need something more specific than that, you can simply create a management page that lets you assign / revoke claims from users.  If you're adding new claims to the system, and either declaratively or programmatically checking whether a user has said claim or not will require you to deploy an update to your application - this isn't that big a deal.  Finally, Roles or Claims - you will still have entries in the DB so...

Comment: Great thanks Brendan. So looks like I'll still need to have some kind of separate table to hold the claims and their groupings i.e. which claims a new user gets, which claims a moderator gets - basically roles! I'm now struggling to see the benefit of claims over traditional roles

Comment: Maybe you need to turn the thinking around.  Basically you have `ClaimTypes.Role`, but it sounds like you are defining a claim (or role) per resource action (read / create / update / delete), rather than allowing a role to access a set of resources and define the set of actions allowed.  This may be of interest to you: http://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly the same question and issue i'm running into. All I found is info on how to create a claim using the manager classes but nothing on where to manage these claims.

There can be different combination of access to give to a user and if my UI is a disconnected UI from my API, I don't think i would want the ui to manage these claims for me.

Other than mucking and creating a claims manager class with a claims table did you figure anything built in that can be used?